# Geb. i am working on this and i need exact Packaging material object can you please let me know

Tags: jquery, spock, geb

[image]

packagingmeterial {By.id($("#menuDiv span").first().text())}

Comment: Would you care elaborate a bit more your question?

Comment: class ApplPage extends BasePage {
 //static url ="baspack-ui/home"
 static content = {
  packagingmeterial {$("#menuDiv span").first().text()} 
  }
 }

Comment: this is my page deceleration and i want pass content

Comment: def "MeterialPacking on with Specification"() {
  
  //given:
  //go "http://localhost:8080/baspack-ui/home"
   
  when:
  to ApplPage
  
  and:
  packagingmeterial.click()
  
  then:
  assert h1Text == "Specification Overview"
  }

Answer (score 0):

This is hard to answer because there are many different ways to get the element you are after. I think the easiest way would be to define the element like this:

`$(By.xpath("//span")).text()`

Since this is the only "span" in the screenshot I will assume it is the only span on the page.

you could also do this, if you need to reference the closest ID:

`$(By.id("#menuform:loggedInMenu_0 span")).children()[0].children()[0].text()`

If you want to use the same element definition that you posted in your question you can do this:

`$(By.id("#menuDiv span")).children()[0].children()[0].children()[0].children()[0].children()[0].children()[0]`

I also noticed something wrong in your comments up above.

in your static content you have defined:

`static content = { packagingmeterial {$("#menuDiv span").first().text()} }`

but then later on you try and call `packagingmeterial.click()` this will not work because packagingmeterial is not a Navigator object it is a String You transform it from a Navigator to a String when you say `.text()`. So you should also try removing that and see if it helps.

You may also benefit from reading the geb docs found here:
http://www.gebish.org/